# Coplanar waveguide for differential trace calculator

Tags: usb, impedance, transmission-line, differential

Although there are plenty of free impedance calculators out there, I'm struggling to find one that can solve impedances for a **differential pair** using coplanar waveguide. Anyone know of any free software that can do that? The only one I was able to find was Si9000 and Si8000m by Polar instruments, but they aren't free.

Reason I'm interested is because I'm trying to route USB 2.0 HS signals on a 2 layer 1.6mm FR4 board and want to see if using coplanar waveguide will make it more practical (i.e. thinner traces).

Amr

Comment: What calculators have you tried (to save a thousand pointless suggestions)?

Comment: [atlc](http://atlc.sourceforge.net/) was mentioned in a recent [question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/117214/impedance-of-an-edge-coupled-coplanar-waveguide-with-ground/117240#117240), however I've never used it myself.

Comment: Also the OP's geometry in that question might help you out.

Comment: I tried this once :)  It is possible but we had trouble because the reference portion of the coplanar waveguide had to be fairly fat compared to the traces so it took away a large section of pins from the chip.  I want to say 1/4" maybe?  Moving it away to make space defeated the point.  Once we found out the true cost difference between a 4 layer board and a 2 layer board at our volumes we convinced mgmt to go with a 4 layer.  By the time you factor in all the advantages including an easier time with EMI...  It just made more sense.  Good luck!

Comment: Oh and we figured out the waveguide by hand based on Wadell's book http://www.amazon.com/Transmission-Handbook-Antennas-Propagation-Microwave/dp/0890064369  I seem to have taken it home or I'd check the pages for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try [TNT](http://www.pdamusician.com/testtechniques/files/TNT_2D_Field_Solver_V1_2_2.exe) or [TxLine](http://www.pdamusician.com/testtechniques/files/TXLine_Transmission_Line_Calculator.zip).

Also note that your best bet may actually be VERY SHORT (few mm) traces, a thinner board or a 4 layer board :-)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Unfortunately, TxLine doesn't do coplanar waveguide for *differential* traces. I checked out TNT, but couldn't seem to be able to do the same with that either.